# kepp text in the middle and position 3 images in the middle with text below it

Tags: css

I am trying to position a text in the middle while having 3 images in a row with text below each other and the last text and image next to each other as shown below. I have been trying to use flexbox. If someone can be kind enough to help I would appreciate it. thank you the design and code are at the bottom.
[image]

here is my code

```
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>Become a Pro with our camp</h2>
        </div>
        
        <section>
<img src="img/diet-icon.png" alt="diet">
<h2>Diet</h2>
<p>Eat what the pros eat.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
<img src="img/training.png" alt="workout">
<h2>Workout</h2>
<p>Workout how the pros do.</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <img src="img/basketball-training.jpg" alt="basketball training">
            <h2>Basketball Training</h2>
            <p>Train like how the pros train.</p>
        </section>
        <section class="section-champ">
            <h2>The beginning towards winning the championship starts here</h2>
            <img src="img/championship-img.jpg" alt="championship" class="champ">
        </section>
    </div>

 .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .wrapper div h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .wrapper section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  .wrapper section img {
    width: 50px;
  }

  .wrapper .section h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  .wrapper section .champ {
    width: 300px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there. That is if I am understanding the question correctly. Codepen example https://codepen.io/nickberens360/pen/RwxLKMd

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">
        <h2>Become a Pro with our camp</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="stuff">
    <section class="icon-group">
        <img src="img/diet-icon.png" alt="diet">
        <h2>Diet</h2>
        <p>Eat what the pros eat.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="icon-group">
        <img src="img/training.png" alt="workout">
        <h2>Workout</h2>
        <p>Workout how the pros do.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="icon-group">
        <img src="img/basketball-training.jpg" alt="basketball training">
        <h2>Basketball Training</h2>
        <p>Train like how the pros train.</p>
    </section>
  </div>
    <section class="section-champ stuff">
        <h2>The beginning towards winning the championship starts here</h2>
        <img src="img/championship-img.jpg" alt="championship" class="champ">
    </section>
</div>

<style>

 .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

.stuff {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 12px;
    border: 1px solid red
}
</style>


  [1]: https://codepen.io/nickberens360/pen/RwxLKMd
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your images/titles sections in a div with flex box.

Below is an example of how the markup and css would look.

HTML:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Become a pro at our camp</h1>
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <div class="img 1">
        <img src="./food.png"/>
        <h5>Diet</h5>
        <p>Eat what the pros eat</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img 2">
        <img src="./dumbbell.png"/>
        <h5>Workout</h5>
        <p>Workout how the pros do.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img 3">
        <img src="./basketball.png"/>
        <h5>Basketball Training</h5>
        <p>Train like the pros train.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
}

.img-wrapper {
  margin-top: 2vw;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2vw;
}

ion-icon {
  font-size: 5vw;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 1vw;
}

.img {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5vw;
}
```

You can find a codepen example of this working [here](https://codepen.io/duncanlutz/pen/XWVepoV)